# speedup Nestjs + jest test performance

Tags: performance, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, nestjs

I wrote about 2,000 testcase in nestjs application with jest.
but it takes around 3 minutes to take overall test.

I want to reduce the time executing these tests.
when i examine the situation, jest adapter function executes every time before the test, and it takes most of the time of the test.

Also, I set all the configuration about speedup jest performance such as maxWorkers, disable type checker(`isolatedModule: true`).

Does any one has solutino to speed up jest performance??? (I attach the screenshot of debugging jest performance)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XtIj.jpg)

Comment: You need to provide more details in order to get answer

Answer (score 0):

Making the test system completely independent from the internet by mocking it will shorten the test time.